# Batch - Figure out if java is installed or not

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, terminal, command-prompt

First to say, I am not experienced with batch-scripts at all.

As the title already tells, I am trying to figure out if `java` is installed on the system or not, from a bat-file. I already checked many ways to do so but most of them seem more complex than what it should take to get this done.

My idea so far was to save the result of `java -version` into a variable and then check if there actually was an result, or if the command `java` couldn't be found. Sadly I couldn't even figure out, how to get the output of `java -version` saved to a variable so i could compare it.

If someone can help me with my idea or has a different simple solution to my problem i would be glad if you could help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
where java >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==1 (
    @echo Java not found in path.
    exit
)
```

The `>nul` and `2>nul` are *optional* and used only to mute the `where` command output.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `java -version` command in your script and saving it to a variable like this: `isJavaInstalled="$(java -version)"`. If Java is installed, the variable should contain something like this:
`java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)`, else the variable is empty.
You can also try to check the value of `JAVA_HOME` system variable which should contain a path to where Java is installed.

Comment: Good solution for Unix-based shells. But I don't think this will work on a Windows `.bat` file...

Comment: You are right, however the approach with `java -version` should work. So maybe `where java` or `echo %JAVA_HOME%` would help?

Comment: Yep! Please see my answer ;)